# Connect to Amazon AWS with GFTP (SSH uses key authentication .pem)

Tags: ssh, amazon-ec2

How do I connect to Amazon AWS and use its key.pem file for authentication?
GFTP doesn't have any option for authenticating through a file.

Similar question on ubuntuforums "[How can i use gftp to connect to an ssh server that only uses key authentication](http://ubuntuforums.org/archive/index.php/t-1067430.html)" answers for users of Filezilla instead of GFTP.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You just need to open GFTP and go to "Options" -> "SSH" -> "Extra parameters for SSH" and add

```
-i /home/user/aws_keypair.pem
```